# I'm having an issue with next auth on vercel its showing me server error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-oauth, next-auth

I used google as an auth provider with next auth. Configured all the the environment variables both in production and development. It's working perfectly in developent mode on my local machine but in production it shows the error "Server error
There is a problem with the server configuration.

Check the server logs for more information" whenever i try to sign in.

I deployed the site to vercel and had setup google id, secret and NEXTAUTH_URL variables there.

This is the code i used for mine

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
export const authOptions = { // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({ 
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID, 
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET, }), // ...add more providers here
  ],
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

I tried adding all the environment variables to vercel as i should but it didnt work i also redeployed it a couple times

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is about nextauth itself.
Both secrets should be set on vercel:

```
jwt: {
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  },
secret: process.env.SECRET,
```